# Unable to build SQL Server OLAP Cube when there is no rows corresponding to foreign key in a table

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube

I am  new to SQL Server OLAP Cubes.  I am having the following issue  like

ex  I have  purchase order and invoice tables  which are used in data source view. These two tables are related  by purchase order ID  which have one to many relationship with invoices.

I am getting the following error for the purcahse orders which i dont have invoices

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: purchase order

Can anyone throw some light  on this to help me

Comment: Use an unknown member in your dimension for missing lookups?

Comment: where can i set this property Mitch?

Answer (score 1):

The most common causes for this error is processing order and NULLs in fact table.

Make sure you process the dimension before processing the measure group.

When key values in the fact table has NULL values, SSAS by default treats it as 0 for INT and '' (Blank) for Char data types. Make sure fact keys don't have NULL values. If there are nulls, one solution is to use a default unknown member in the dimension table (usually -1) and replace null in the fact table to -1.